# IDEA no longer compiling project before run

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I loaded a Maven project in IDEA 2018.1.5. I configured an "Application" run/debug configuration to run it.

I could have sworn that in the past, IDEA would automatically invoke "Build Project" before Run/Debug if any source files had changed. Then something happened recently, and it no longer does. Now, every time I run/debug the project, it runs the compiled code even if it's stale (ignoring changes I made to the source-code).

I checked Settings -> Compiler -> "Build project automatically" is on. I think I tried disabling it at one point and I did not notice a difference. What other setting could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Edit run configurations, select the good one, make sure "Build" is present in the "Before launch" at the bottom of the dialog box.

Comment: @JBNizet That was it. Thank you! If you post a formal answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit run configurations, select the good one, make sure "Build" is present in the "Before launch" at the bottom of the dialog box.